# Fluid dynamics question

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Consider 2 cubes one resting horizontally with a hole at the bottom corner , we can say that the speed of water coming out of there is sqrt(2gh) if the hole is considerably small , what about the rate of flow from the hole when the hole is made at an edge and it is made the lowest point of the cube . I know the answer but not the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the volumetric flow rate, then you have

$$ \dot{V} = \mathbf{v}\,A = \frac{\pi\,d^2}{4}\,\sqrt{2\,g\,h} $$

where $d$ is the diameter of the hole. If you mean the mass flow rate, then you just multiply the volumetric flow rate by the density.

$$\dot{m} = \rho\,\dot{V}$$

You just need to substitute $h$ for the correct level. If you have the hole at the corner and at the edge, both at the bottom of the cube, for practical purposes you have the same exit velocity.

Comment: I have the hole only at the edge and how did you arrive on the first function?

Comment: Also you are saying that when the  hole is on the edge the velocity will be √2gh which is wrong

Comment: The velocity as you can see is $\sqrt{2\,g\,h}$, therefore it is only dependent on $h$, while the rest are constants. Unless you are looking for some super complex Navier-Stokes solution, I am pretty sure the velocities at the same height level are the same on the exits.

Comment: The first equation is well known, given that the hole is circular, it's area is used and multiplied by the exit velocity to get the volumetric flow rate.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought but there is a different answer in the book I am studying , it must be wrong then , thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If you want, show me the diagram from your book or something, I could try to make sense of it. Also you can post the answer from the book, we'll try to figure out what could happen.

Comment: I don't have the solution , I just have the answer as √2gh / 4th root of 2 , which is absurd